# How to traverse peg through all the squares in a Monopoly type Game in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to traverse the peg through all the squares in a Monopoly type board Game ?

I have written a function for the movepegbutton which on click moves the peg to the destination position which it gets from the random generated number.

This is what I have written so far for the Move peg Button.

```
(IBAction)movePegButton:(id)sender
{
    self.pegDestinationPositionIndex = self.pegCurrentPositionIndex + self.randomNumber;
    if (self.pegDestinationPositionIndex > [self.boardCordinatesArray count] - 1)
    {
         self.pegDestinationPositionIndex = self.pegDestinationPositionIndex - [self.boardCordinatesArray count];
    }
    [self animatePeg];
    self.pegCurrentPositionIndex = self.pegDestinationPositionIndex;
}
```

This is what I have written to animate the peg.

```
(void)animatePeg
{
    int destinationXCord = [[[self.boardCordinatesArray objectAtIndex:self.pegDestinationPositionIndex] objectForKey:@"x"]intValue];
    int destinationYCord = [[[self.boardCordinatesArray objectAtIndex:self.pegDestinationPositionIndex] objectForKey:@"y"]intValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.peg.center = CGPointMake(destinationXCord, destinationYCord);
    }];
}
```

So far the peg moves correctly to the destination square but it is not traversing through all the squares in its way, for e.g. if it is 8X8 square, for first run dice rolls 6, the peg moves correctly to 6th square, for second run dice rolls 5, the peg moves correctly to the destination square but it directly jumps over to that position diagonally, it doesn't traverse the squares which it has in its way.

I am stuck here, how should i do it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your peg is supposed to walk in a square, ei. follow the edge of the board, but instead cuts corners, am I right?

If I am so, then the answer is very straight forward. To make sure that the peg follows the squares lain on the board, you must make it move to every square in the path from source square to destination square, otherwise it will simply cut the corner and go straight for the destination square.

If the player rolls a 4, and is standing on square 9 and must reach square 13. Then instead of making the peg move directly to square 13, I would force the peg to go first to 10, then 11, then 12 and then at last square 13.
Of course if the squares are aligned in a square manor, that is; four edges, then some optimization could be done, and only split up the path if a corner is in between the source square and the destination square.
And of course this optimization could also be applied even though the squares are not aligned in a square like manor, just as long as it follows some path, and you know where the 'corners' are.

Edit:
[image: The described three cases]
To try and test my paint skills and to try and visualize the problem at hand, I have created something within paint.

What you are doing in the presented code is **Case 1**. You are doing a *single* animation when moving the peg. What you really want do is **Case 2**, here your function `-(void)animatePeg;` should recognize that the destination square is more than 1 square away, and therefore not do a *single*  move animation, but a series of move animations, to be more precise, the number of animations is always `indexOfDestinationSquare - indexOfSourceSquare`. So in the illustrated case, the peg should do a total of *eight* move animations instead of only *one*.

**Case 3** shows how this process could be optimized by recognizing the direction of the move, and only split when going around a corner.

I hope this clarifies what approach I would take. To do this approach you need to extend your `-(void)animatePeg;` function to be able to split up the single move into a series of moves, and then animate the moves one-by-one.

Comment: yes, that's what i want it to do, but its not going through the squares which are in its way. I am not getting how do I optimize it so that it moves through all the squares.

Comment: After you've thought out your design a bit based in @ArniDat's great answer, look into *animateWithDuration:animations:completion:* to chain together multiple animations.